# Jqueryui tabs load .js files (included in external files) with a dynamic query string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jqueryui tabs where each tab is pointing to an external .php file(of-course except first tab) like this :

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Home Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="content1.php">Second tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="content2.php">Third tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="content3.php">Forth Tab tab</a></li> </ul>
        <!----------- remaining content ------------>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I am having external `.js` files attached to `content1`, `content2` and `content3`.

The problem is that whenever I click on Second tab , the `content1.php` file loads fine but `.js` files attached to it loads with a dynamic query string attached to it like this:

> http://localhost/jqueryui-tabs/dropzone.js?_=1454222717666
>
> http://localhost/jqueryui-tabs/jquery.slimscroll.min.js?_=1454222717667

and same with all .js which I include .

This is the code for `content1.php` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Document</title>
       <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/dropzone.css" /> 
   </head>
   <body>
        <div class="image_upload">
            <form action="upload.php" method="POST" class="dropzone">
            </form>
        </div> 
        <script src="dropzone.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have already researched a lot and can't find any similar question.

P.s I can't include all `.js` files in the very first tab as `dropzone.js` would probably not work and page load time will increase .

So what could be causing those query strings? I am not using anything special besides `jqueryui-tabs` that could cause it.

Thank you.

Comment: just jquery adding a timestamp to prevent caching

Comment: can i remove that? If yes the then how?

Comment: try setting `cache: true` .. won't reload html either though if that is needed

Comment: Can you expand please as I am a newbie. Exactly where to put cache as true  ?

Comment: in the tabs options object

Comment: ok i tried it, but still no success. Query strings are still there.

Comment: how it's progress? Please share solution if you resolved it.